# Call C# code embedded in razor form

Tags: c#, ajax, razor

A while back I found this interesting little trick here: [Assign JavaScript variable value to ASP.Net Session variable using JQuery AJAX](http://aspforums.net/Threads/184700/Assign-JavaScript-variable-value-to-ASPNet-Session-variable-using-JQuery-AJAX/)

It embeds a C# WebMethod in an .aspx form and then calls it through ajax. Is there a similar technique that can be applied to a razor form? Can razor forms even be used that way? Or tricked in a similar way as a controller? I experimented a little with no luck, so looking for suggestions on something I might have missed.

To be clear: is it possible to embed C# code in a razor page and then call that code from that page, as in the example, above.

Comment: The equivalent would be to use JQuery to call an MVC or web API controller action that returned JSON.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in the example given, the C# code being called is embedded in the page not in a separate controller. I'm asking if it's possible to do similar with razor.

Comment: The example you link to is calling a WebMethod on a asp.net web form, which is just a simple web service. There is no View/Controller separation in a web form, and a web form is not analogous to a Razor view.

Comment: It appears you are confused by all the technologies.  The javascript in your linked example would work literally on *any* programming technology.  It doesn't matter if it's ASP.Net, Perl, Php, Python, pure HTml they could all call via Ajax that method, or a method by any number of technologies.  *is it possible to embed C# code in a razor page:* Yes, *then call that code from that page, as in the example, above:* No *AND* that not what the code above is doing *at all*.

Comment: Erik? Please note that the example is identified as "Client Side" and that the url in the ajax call is: CS.aspx/SetSession. I.e. "Client Side aspx". And I did, in fact, test this example before I posted and it did, in fact, work. :) Also note my first two questions: Can similar be done and is it even possible? I'd rather see if a closed door can be opened rather than just blindly assuming it's closed without even trying. Nothing ventured, nothing gained.